# API Gateway High Availability

Tags: api

If API gateway fails (single entry point to the system), then unable to access all the services. Any HA(High Availability) design to handle API gateway failure?

Answer (score 1):

1) As per your project location, you can choose one more region as your disaster recovery plan. When ever something fails in one region then immediately you can switch to another region by just changing the end point.

2) You can use services like route53 to divide your traffic between two regions or two api gateways. That way you will save atleast part of your traffic flowing even if one apig fails.

3) Always keep cloudwatch alarms to get notification about any failures in your system.

4) It is very unlikely that a api gateway will fail. It is AWS my friend.

Comment: Today, it has failed and here I'm looking for a solution. LOL

Answer (score 1):

"node_saini" has a great response and it's correct. I tried to comment but don't have the reputation to do so yet... the comment would say:

5) Configure your timeout to fail ASAP based on baselines and implement [retries with exponential backoff](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html) on 5xx errors to alleviate any small percentage of failures which may occur.

With all applications, temporary failures are expected but permanent failures after retry can be a sign of a real problem brewing.